Build Error: Preline Library Fails to Compile in Next.js TypeScript Project

I’m using the preline/preline library in my Next.js (TypeScript) project. I followed the installation and setup instructions provided in the documentation. However, I’m encountering a build error that prevents the project from compiling. Below is the error message:
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

Steps to Reproduce:

Installed preline using npm
Followed the configuration steps from the documentation.
Ran the development server using npm run dev

Environment Details:
•   Next.js Version: 15.1.0
•   TypeScript: Enabled
•   Node.js Version: v20.15.1

PrelineScriot.tsx

custom.d.ts

layout.tsx

I tried to remedy the situation as follows


Please do not add pictures of your code. We cannot copy it or modify it. Add your code as formatted text.

I fixed this and reverted the version from 2.0.6 to 2.0.3.
